# set calculated property on model only once

Tags: python-3.x, django

im using python3 + django, and i have

- a model of User with few fields
- an admin page where all the users are presented
- a form page where a single user is presented and can be updated
- an external API with 2 endpoints:

  1. `GET /api/users/name` (get all names for all the users)
  2. `GET /api/users/:id/name`  (get name for user by id)

i want to add a `name` property to be presented on admin page (as a column) and on a form page (read-only, not changeable)

how can i add this "calculated" property without calling an api more than needed?

Answer (score 0):

it is normal function, you should create new method in ModelAdminand you can use result of this method in render.
more here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields

if you want to get username as readonly in list and in form, add this method in `list_display` and in `field` or `fieldsets` `Modeladmin` options.

You don't need to use other api, if you has already users list.